Unable to modify PostgreSQL database row using the following SQLAlchemy statement
I'm unable to modify Data row using the following SQLAlchemy statement:
stmt = (
    update(models.Data)
    .values(
        custom_columns=(
            func.coalesce(
                func.jsonb_set(
                    func.jsonb_set(
                        cast(models.Data.custom_columns, JSONB), 
                        '{archived}', 
                        cast(
                            models.Data.custom_columns['archived'], 
                            JSONB
                        ).op('||')(
                            func.jsonb_build_object(
                                old_key, 
                                cast(
                                    models.Data.custom_columns['fields'][old_key], 
                                    JSONB
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    '{fields}', 
                    cast(
                        cast(models.Data.custom_columns, JSONB)['fields'], 
                        JSONB
                    ).op('-')(old_key)
                ),
                cast(models.Data.custom_columns, JSONB)
            )
        ),
        updated_at=func.now()
    )
    .where(
        cast(models.Data.custom_columns, JSONB)['fields'].has_key(old_key)
    )
    .where(models.Data.project_id == project_id)
)


Can someone help?

Tried to delete key, value from "fields" inside "custom_columns" and create "archived" inside custom_columns and add deleted key, value in "archived"


Can you include what happened?  Did you get an error or was the value just not changed to what you expected?  Also I only see an update statement, are you executing the update?

When I execute this statement, the data row is not modified and I want to modify it like this: Delete key, value from "fields" inside "custom_columns" and create "archived" inside custom_columns and add deleted key, value in "archived"

This is how I fixed the code:
stmt = (
                update(models.Data)
                .values(
                    custom_columns=func.coalesce(
                        func.jsonb_set(
                            func.jsonb_set(
                                cast(models.Data.custom_columns, JSONB),
                                "{archived}",
                                func.coalesce(
                                    cast(
                                        models.Data.custom_columns["archived"], JSONB
                                    ).op("||")(
                                        func.jsonb_build_object(
                                            old_key,
                                            cast(
                                                models.Data.custom_columns["fields"][
                                                    old_key
                                                ],
                                                JSONB,
                                            ),
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    func.jsonb_build_object(
                                        old_key,
                                        cast(
                                            models.Data.custom_columns["fields"][
                                                old_key
                                            ],
                                            JSONB,
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                                True,
                            ),
                            "{fields}",
                            func.coalesce(
                                cast(
                                    cast(models.Data.custom_columns, JSONB)["fields"],
                                    JSONB,
                                ).op("-")(old_key),
                                func.jsonb_build_object(),
                            ),
                            True,
                        ),
                        cast(models.Data.custom_columns, JSONB),
                    ),
                    updated_at=func.now(),
                )
                .where(
                    cast(models.Data.custom_columns, JSONB)["fields"].has_key(old_key)
                )
                .where(models.Data.project_id == project_id)
            )

